# How to set background image inside of default Calendar and custom Calendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calendar

[image][image: I am displaying sample calendar image for reference]

I am new to iOS App Development.I googled but no appropriate result found.
I am trying to set background image to calendar.i want to apply background image inside the calendar not outside of it. Any alternatives to do task.
Any valuable suggestions will be appreciated.

"Thanks in Advance"

Comment: have you tried to set image in background in this view controller like self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE"]];

Comment: I tried with it but image was not setting for it...

Comment: use Tapkulibrary. you can customise it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ckcalendar

**Edited Code**

In this example 
Add following line in this method in `CKViewController.m`

```
- (id)init {
         calendar.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bird.jpg"]];
    }
```

And make evertthing clearcolor(or as per your requirement) in `- (void)layoutSubviews` of `CKCalendarView.m`

Comment: I want to set background image of entire block backside of dates inside the calendar.....

Comment: Still to set 2nd link in tapku library...I will do now

Comment: @Vidhyanand see this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65213224/CalDemo%202.zip i have already implemented but it has 24 calendar which you can change

Comment: I modified the question.Check it @Dhara.

Comment: is there any way i can add dateItem background image?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are using `CKCalendar`.
to set background image,

**Try this**

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

**in**

```
- (void)setDefaultStyle 
{
}
```

method from `CKCalendarView.m`

Comment: i try with it but i want to set background image inside the calendar not backside of it.....

Comment: is there any way i can add dateItem background image?